# cant connect internet after installing dnscrypt

Tags: 17.10, dnscrypt-proxy

i was installing dnscrypt proxy in ubuntu 17.10 following guide below

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2017/11/how-to-install-dnscrypt-on-ubuntu-1710.html?m=1

it all went well and dnscrypt working fine. the next time i turn on the computer i just can't connect to internet. so i tried to uninstall dnscrypt proxy and refollow the guide to undo the change i made but it still doesn't connect. i have no idea what wrong here and i really appreciate any help.

**edit:**

somehow i'm able to solve my problem. i'm not really sure why. i'll write it so it might help other who have similar problem.

i edit /etc/resolv.conf and change so it looks like this

> nameserver 127.0.0.53

then i flush my dns using

> $  sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service

Comment: `dnscrypt-proxy` might have not been set to start up when you start the computer. Try following the instructions, but adding `sudo systemctl enable dnscrypt-proxy`.

Comment: when i got the problem i promptly uninstall dnscrypt-proxy just to found out it does nothing to solve the problem. i'll keep this in mind in the future. thanks for the reply.

Comment: quto of `/etc/resolv.conf`:
*# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN*

Comment: Also for dnscrypt to work, have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/622115/how-to-run-dnscrypt-proxy-in-vivid?rq=1 The main problem if dnscrypt is not working after a fresh install might be the Local IP that dnscrypt is listening to. If dnscrypt is using 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 it can happen. You should switch to 127.0.0.2 than. This is how i did run my dnscrypt that i did download from dnscrypt.org: `sudo /opt/dnscrypt-proxy/x86_64-linux-musl/bin/dnscrypt-proxy --resolver-name=soltysiak --local-address=127.0.0.2 --user=dnscrypt-user`